# Problems using Symfony2 + PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, deprecation-warning

I've finished my first "real" web-application using Symfony2. Until now there are no unit tests - since the project grows very fast - I need to add them to check for errors before every release. (Currently I test everything manually)

When i first use "phpunit -c app/" i get this deprecation-messages:

> Remaining deprecation notices (37)
>
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::setFactoryMethod(createNamed)
>   is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use
>   Definition::setFactory() instead: 4x
>       4x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::setFactoryService(form.factory)
>   is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use
>   Definition::setFactory() instead: 4x
>       4x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The "pattern" option in file
>   "/var/www/myproject/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
>   is deprecated since version 2.2 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the
>   "path" option in the route definition instead: 3x
>       3x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> Twig Function "form_enctype" is deprecated. Use "form_start" instead
>   in FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit_content.html.twig at line 1: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> Using an instance of "Twig_Function_Method" for function
>   "vich_uploader_asset" is deprecated since version 1.21. Use
>   Twig_SimpleFunction instead: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The Twig_Function class is deprecated since version 1.12 and will be
>   removed in 2.0. Use Twig_SimpleFunction instead: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The "scope" attribute of service
>   "fos_user.resetting.form.handler.default" in file
>   "/var/www/myproject/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/resetting.xml"
>   is deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The Twig_Function_Method class is deprecated since version 1.12 and
>   will be removed in 2.0. Use Twig_SimpleFunction instead: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> Twig Function "form_enctype" is deprecated. Use "form_start" instead
>   in FOSUserBundle:Group:new_content.html.twig at line 1: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> Twig Function "form_enctype" is deprecated. Use "form_start" instead
>   in FOSUserBundle:Group:edit_content.html.twig at line 1: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> Twig Function "form_enctype" is deprecated. Use "form_start" instead
>   in FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig at line 1: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> Twig Function "form_enctype" is deprecated. Use "form_start" instead
>   in FOSUserBundle:ChangePassword:changePassword_content.html.twig at
>   line 1: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The "_method" requirement of route "fos_user_security_check" in file
>   "/var/www/myproject/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
>   is deprecated since version 2.2 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the
>   "methods" attribute instead: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> Twig Function "form_enctype" is deprecated. Use "form_start" instead
>   in FOSUserBundle:Resetting:reset_content.html.twig at line 1: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The "factory-service" attribute of service "fos_user.resetting.form"
>   in file
>   "/var/www/myproject/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/resetting.xml"
>   is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the
>   "factory" element instead: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The "scope" attribute of service
>   "fos_user.change_password.form.handler.default" in file
>   "/var/www/myproject/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/change_password.xml"
>   is deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The "factory-method" attribute of service "fos_user.profile.form" in
>   file
>   "/var/www/myproject/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/profile.xml"
>   is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the
>   "factory" element instead: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The "factory-service" attribute of service "fos_user.profile.form" in
>   file
>   "/var/www/myproject/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/profile.xml"
>   is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the
>   "factory" element instead: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::setFactoryService(doctrine)
>   is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use
>   Definition::setFactory() instead: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The "factory-service" attribute of service "fos_user.entity_manager"
>   in file
>   "/var/www/myproject/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/orm.xml"
>   is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the
>   "factory" element instead: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::setFactoryMethod(getManager)
>   is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use
>   Definition::setFactory() instead: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The "scope" attribute of service
>   "fos_user.profile.form.handler.default" in file
>   "/var/www/myproject/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/profile.xml"
>   is deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The "factory-method" attribute of service "fos_user.registration.form"
>   in file
>   "/var/www/myproject/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/registration.xml"
>   is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the
>   "factory" element instead: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The "factory-service" attribute of service
>   "fos_user.change_password.form" in file
>   "/var/www/myproject/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/change_password.xml"
>   is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the
>   "factory" element instead: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The "factory-method" attribute of service "fos_user.entity_manager" in
>   file
>   "/var/www/myproject/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/orm.xml"
>   is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the
>   "factory" element instead: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The "factory-method" attribute of service
>   "fos_user.change_password.form" in file
>   "/var/www/myproject/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/change_password.xml"
>   is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the
>   "factory" element instead: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The "scope" attribute of service
>   "fos_user.registration.form.handler.default" in file
>   "/var/www/myproject/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/registration.xml"
>   is deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The "factory-service" attribute of service
>   "fos_user.registration.form" in file
>   "/var/www/myproject/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/registration.xml"
>   is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the
>   "factory" element instead: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller
>
> The "factory-method" attribute of service "fos_user.resetting.form" in
>   file
>   "/var/www/myproject/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/resetting.xml"
>   is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the
>   "factory" element instead: 1x
>       1x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller

After the first time (cache got build) only this remains:

Remaining deprecation notices (320)

> The class "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Config\AsseticResource" is
>   performing resource checking through ResourceInterface::isFresh(),
>   which is deprecated since 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0: 320x
>       320x in myControllerTest::testMyAction from MyNamespace\XYZBundle\Tests\Controller

I searched how to suppress deprecated warnings as they are from dependencies and not from my code. I found this solution:

```
<php>
<ini name="error_reporting" value="-16385" />
</php>
```

So I added this to my phpunit.xml but it doesn't solve the problem. Hope you can help me with it!

Answer (score 5):

This summary of deprecations is shown by the Symfony PHPunit bridge. It has a deprecations helper, that stores all deprecation notices that were triggered and show them after all tests have run.

The deprecations helper can be configured using the `SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER` env variable. This can have a couple different values:

- `weak` - indicates that the current deprecation notices are caused by third party libraries. It'll now only show `Remaining deprecation notices (320)` and the test script will return `0` (success).
- **Any number** - indicates the number of deprecation notices that are allowed. In your case, you know that 320 deprecation notices are caused by Assetic and not your code. If you set `SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER` to `320`, the build will pass as long as the number of notices is below 320. This is very usefull, as it'll warn you as soon as you introduce new deprecations.
- **A regex** - This will stop the build as soon as a deprecation was triggered that matches the regex. This is usefull to debug deprecation notices.

Setting the env variable can be done on the command line:

```
# unix
$ SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=320 phpunit -c app
# windows
> set SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER=320
> phpunit -c app
```

Or in the `phpunit.xml(.dist)` file:

```
<php>
    <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="320"/>
</php>
```

Comment: Using the variable in unix-command is working. If I put the env-variable into my phpunit.xml.dist file it get loaded but the deprecation messages which gets produced in the test file still showen.

Comment: I suspect that the config file is processed too late for the bridge

Comment: @nPoday turns out that was due to a syntax mistake I made. It's now fixed